# OpenMP about for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, openmp

I have a OpenMP code snippet as follows:

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
  #pragma omp parallel for default(none) \
  private(i, a_output) \
  shared(n, t_input, t0, trace_amp)
#endif
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if( t_input >= t0[i] )
        {

                a_output = trace_amp[i];

                return a_output;
        }
    }
```

Is this code correct? Why `a_output` has to be private? Can it be shared?

Comment: Did you ask a compiler before asking here?

Comment: Having that `return` statement in the loop makes your program non-conforming (to OpenMP) since you're branching out of the parallel region.

Comment: You have to be more specific on question title :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @1201ProgramAlarm said, you cannot have a `return` statement inside a parallel region. The compilers do not even compile the code

```
$ gcc Untitled-1.c -fopenmp
Untitled-1.c: In function ‘main’:
Untitled-1.c:7:20: error: invalid branch to/from OpenMP structured block
             return a_output;

$ clang Untitled-1.c -fopenmp=libomp
Untitled-1.c:7:13: error: cannot return from OpenMP region
            return a_output;
            ^
1 error generated.
```

However, the version 4.0 of the OpenMP specification brings a new directive: `cancel`. With it, you can interrupt the execution of a parallel region. It adds a bit of overhead to the total execution time because in each iteration the threads test whether they have to stop or not.

You can try rewrite the original for-loop this way:

```c
  a_output = 0;
#ifdef _OPENMP
  #pragma omp parallel default(none) \
  private(i) \
  shared(n, t_input, t0, trace_amp, a_output)
  #pragma omp for
#endif
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
      if( t_input >= t0[i] ){
              a_output = trace_amp[i];
              #pragma omp cancel for
      }
      #pragma omp cancellation point for

  }
  return a_output;
```

You must separate the `for` from `parallel` to avoid use a implicit `nowait` clause on for

EDIT: as stated by @Zulan

1) There must be at least one cancellation point that all threads can naturally reach if a cancellation should occur. Although the `cancel` directive itself has a cancellation point by definition, it is within an if statement that may not be accessed by all threads. The solution to this is to add a `cancellation point` outside the if statement. I changed the code to match this.

2) The cancellation is disabled by default in most runtimes. To enable, one should set the `OMP_CANCELLATION` environment variable to true.

3) There is still a race condition in `a_output`. Unless you are sure that there is only one value less than `t_input` within`t0`, there is a possibility that two or more threads will write to `a_output` before cancellation occurs. You should review the logic behind your code to confirm if this is a problem or not.

Comment: Thanks for this solution.

Comment: 1) Cancellation works only at cancellation points (there are none in your example) 2) Cancellation is disabled by defaut, 3) The code still has a race condition on on `a_output`.